# Node.js javascript command line while server running?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have a node.js web server running with express, is there a way to get a command line? Kind of like the way the browser has a javascript console. I want to type in variables and inspect them in node.js runtime.

If I type in 'node' then it gives me a command line. but if I type in 'node server.js' that command line is not available. How can I make the command line always available (in bottom of screen) regardless of the server's state?

Comment: You really have two options. 1: Open another terminal. 2: Use something like pm2 (an npm package) that runs a script in the background and frees up your command line. I use pm2 on all my node servers. https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

Comment: @JakeAve the question is asking about opening a console to inspect variables at runtime, not about having another terminal open (or not being able to use the terminal while the express app is running)

Comment: That makes more sense! I have never heard of anything besides like the vs code debugger that lets you see variables at runtime (unless you want to add console logs all over your server), but I'll follow this question and see if something else is out there.

Answer (score 1):

To do this type `node --inspect server.js`

Then to connect to it type in `chrome://inspect/` in url bar of Chrome. Then click "inspect" on that instance under Remote Target. Then I found I can see variables/objects that are under the `global` namespace.

Also, a very basic way to add keyboard interaction on the server window itself without having to connect to it:

```
var readline = require('readline');
readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);

setInterval(function() {
    console.log('server stuff');
}, 1000);

process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {

    if(key.sequence === '\u0003') {
        console.log('ctrl-c pressed');
        process.exit();
    }

    console.log('you pressed: ' + key.name);
});
```

Comment: if using nodemon make sure to start it with -I or setRawMode won't work.